# Cerberus Report LocalDB migration

Tags: sql, localdb

Does anyone know how to migrate Cerberus FTP report database(LocalDB) to a new server?  It seems that on the new install of Cerberus on new machine creates a new db.  I want the history from the old install copied to this server.  I am aware that there are MDF and LDF files.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I tried copying the MDF files to the new server and that does not work

Comment: Make a backup and restore that?

Comment: You can’t bu.  It’s localdb.

Comment: A LocalDB instance is nothing more or less than an SQL Server Express instance with some tweaks (like only accepting connections from particular named pipes by default, and ignoring certain configuration settings). It certainly supports making and restoring backups! Plonk an instance of Management Studio on your machine, start it as the appropriate user if the application is not running under your own credentials, and connect to the instance as usual (`(localdb)\instancename`, use `sqllocaldb info` from the command line if you don't know the name).

Comment: I do not have the full SQL Server express on the machine.  Just the LocalDB.  I cant seem to get this accomplished.  I just want to move it to the new machine and cant seem to do that.

Comment: You don't need SQL Server Express; LocalDB is already installed. What you need is [Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). You should also check where `sqllocaldb` is (it should be somewhere in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<version>\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe`. This is the command-line tool to manage LocalDB instances.

Comment: It wont restore on the new machine.  Says it needs to be in single user mode.  From what I read you cannot put localdb into single user mode.  Now what?

Comment: `USE master; ALTER DATABASE <mydatabase> SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; RESTORE DATABASE ...;`. You cannot put the whole *server* in single-user mode, but that shouldn't be necessary unless you're trying to restore a system database like `master` (which is indeed not possible with LocalDB, but not really meaningful either).